# Advert javascript not being served correctly to the browser unless called directly?

Tags: javascript, iframe, httprequest, ads

I hope this is the right place to ask this question - I did have a look at the rest of the sites in the network but this looked like the most appropriate place.

We are having issues serving third party adverts on our websites. For various reasons our ad setup is a bit complicated - we serve third party javascript tags (AppNexus) through our own ad server (OpenX) through iframes. Currently, the third party javascript tags are not showing correctly, although they have worked just fine in the past.

Debugging this in Safari I have discovered a few things which seem to me to be a bit unusual, and I'm struggling to work out what's going on. Using the web inspector to check the third party's javascript, it appears in the web inspector as a blank file. Additionally, if I check the network tab, the headers are shown and look fine, but there is no 'content' tab with which to check the returned content. The network tab shows the request for the file as complete, and with suitable status codes (200/302):

http://cl.ly/401C1D3Y3u2G2k2k3s0x

However, if I load the file directly in the web browser, it loads fine:

http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=694021&cb=[CACHEBUSTER]&pubclick=[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]

FWIW, the javascript file uses document.write to spit out either an image or another iframe. It's also worth mentioning that there are no related errors in the console - there is one relating to Google Ads, but the problem persists if I load the Ad server's iframe directly without the rest of the site.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before, where a file loads just fine directly, but is (blank / not retrieved / not parsed / whatever's going on) when called as part of another page? If so, would you be able to help me fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me - I hope this makes some sense and will be happy to provide any further information that might help me get to the bottom of this!

Ollie

Comment: Try checking it with Firebug and Opera Dragonfly. maybe you'll spot some other clues. Yet, i think your http `referer` field might be the reason for different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the third party site is filtering output from their servers based on the HTTP referer being sent in the request (a technique employed by many web hosts to thwart hot-linking content).  Try putting the link to the javascript file in a clickable link on a web page on your server and click it and then see if it loads or if you get a blank page.  You could also try loading a browser extension which lets you forge the HTTP Referer (such as [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/?src=search) for Firefox) and then change your refer to be your site instead of the third party's and try pasting in the URL to the browser and see if it loads.

This isn't your fault if it's what turns out to be the actual problem.  It's up to the third party to configure their web host to allow for this.